# udp client sending ICMP “port unreachable” when receiveing messages from the server

Tags: networking, iptables, udp, icmp

(Note: I moved this question from StackOverflow, because it's to be considered off-topic there, better fits here, and still unsolved)

I have a udp client using luasocket, basically doing this (with a few layers of abstraction, but this is what's going on there):

```
s=socket.udp()
s:setsockname("*",0)
s:setpeername(socket.dns.toip("example.com"),64299)
s:settimeout(0)
s:send(...)
s:settimeout(10)
msg,err=s:receive()
s:settimeout(0)
print(msg,err)
```

while seeing everything's fine in the server's debug output (ssh to the remote host), i get a "timeout" error in the client.

when inspecting everything with client-side wireshark, I see the packet my client sent, and a response packet from the server (correct port and everything), AND an ICMP "port unreachable" packet sent from my client host to the server in response to it's (correct) response.

what's going on there? I tried everything, including resetting my iptables to "accept everything", but my client still sends the "port unreachable".

the relevant packets are:

```
From            To                  Len Description
192.168.2.100   95.143.172.171  UDP 61  Source port: 45025  Destination port: 64299
  000e8f11e7000025229835a908004500002f4008400040112b6fc0a802645f8facabafe1fb2b001b28d794d2000ec8360100aa81a477616e74a3756964
95.143.172.171  192.168.2.100   UDP 60  Source port: 64299  Destination port: 45025
  0025229835a9000e8f11e70008004500002b000040003911727b5f8facabc0a80264fb2bafe100172e8d94d2000e0ea10100a681a3756964ff000000
192.168.2.100   95.143.172.171  ICMP 85 Destination unreachable (Port unreachable)
  000e8f11e7000025229835a9080045c00047061d00004001a492c0a802645f8facab0303cc6c000000004500002b000040003911727b5f8facabc0a80264fb2bafe100172e8d94d2000e0ea10100a681a3756964ff
```

Firewall, in case it's important (which I don't think, because iptables doesn't increment any INPUT packet counters while this happens):

```
$ sudo iptables -S
-P INPUT DROP
-P FORWARD DROP
-P OUTPUT ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i eth0 -p udp -m udp --sport 64299 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i eth0 -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 8 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A FORWARD -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 10001:30000 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A OUTPUT -o lo -j ACCEPT
```

both client and server use exactly the same code, so something on my client host seems to interfere with the incoming response packet.

TL;DR timeline:

- client application opens UDP socket, "connecting" to the server
- client application sends request packet
- server application receives request packet
- server application sends response packet
- client host receives response packet (verified by wireshark on client)
- client host sends ICMP Port Unreachable (noticed in wireshark on client)
- client application receives read timeout after 10 seconds
- (just tried:) sending more packets from the client to the server does work, so the socket didn't get closed.

Comment: Did you find a solution this? I am facing the same issue now

Comment: @vk_gst i did, but sadly i don't know for sure anymore how, and i don't have that old code anymore, but i think it had something to do with the way luasocket handles UDP and setpeername, i think there was some undocumented uglyness going on there, first thing i'd try is sending it explicitely to the remote ip:port each time ( i think there's a "send to" function ) instead of trying to have the socket remember the peer. i *think* the issue was that when you setpeername it goes into some kind of "send only to that peer mode" and forgets to accept incoming packets or something like that.

Comment: @vk_gst but as i said, not 100% sure, it could also have been some weirdness with the networking equipment playing into this, but i don't think so.